Transforming three distinct non-collinear points to three distinct non-collinear points.
Let $G = \{T(z) = az + b\bar{z} + c: a,b,c \in \mathbb{C},|a| \neq |b|\}$. I want to show that there exists a transformation $T$ in G such that it sends three distinct non-collinear points to another three distinct non-collinear points, say $T(z_i) = w_i$ for $i=1,2,3$.
proof attempt:
My idea was to find a transformation $T_1$ that sends $0,1,i $ to $z_1,z_2,z_3$ respectively and another transformation $T_2$ such that $T_2(z_1) = w_1, $ $T_2(z_2) = w_2$ and $T_2(z_3) = w_3$ and then composing $T_2$ with the inverse $T_1$ would give the desired transformation.
I computed $T(0) = c := z_1$ and $T(1) = a + b + c = a + b + z_1 := z_2$ and $T(i) = i(a-b) + c = i(a-b) + z_1 :=z_3$ and tried to explicitly solve for $a$ and $b$ and show that $|a| \neq |b|$ but failed to do so.
I don't know if I am on the right track or not. So if you can give me a hint or a help of any kind I would be thankful. Thanks in advance.

You are on the right track. You need to prove two things:

For any three distinct non-collinear points $z_1, z_2, z_3$ there is a transformation $T \in G$ with $T(0) = z_1$, $T(1) = z_2$, $T(i) = z_3$.
Each transformation $T \in G$ has an inverse transformation $T^{-1} \in G$.

For the first part one gets the linear equation system
$$
 \begin{align}
   c &= z_1 \\
a + b + c &= z_2 \\
ia -ib + c &= z_3
\end{align}
$$
which has the solution
$$
\begin{align}
 a&= \frac 12 ((z_2-z_1) -i (z_3-z_1)) \\
 b&= \frac 12 ((z_2-z_1) +i (z_3-z_1)) \\
\end{align}
$$
It remains to verify that $|a| \ne |b|$. Using the formula $|z+w|^2 = |z|^2 + |w|^2 + 2 \operatorname{Re}(z \overline w)$ we have
$$
|a|^2 - |b|^2 =  \operatorname{Re}\left((z_2-z_1) \cdot i \cdot\overline{(z_3-z_1)}\right)\\
= - \operatorname{Im}\left((z_2-z_1) \cdot \overline{(z_3-z_1)}\right)\\
= - |z_3-z_1|^2 \operatorname{Im} \left( \frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}\right)
$$
and that is not zero because $(z_2-z_1)/(z_3-z_1)$ is not a real number (otherwise the three points would be collinear).
For the second part one can solve the equations
$$
 \begin{align}
 az + b \bar z + c &= w \\
 \bar b z + \bar a\bar z + c &= \bar w
\end{align}
$$
for $z$. This has a unique solution because the determinant of the coefficients is $a \bar a - b \bar b = |a|^2 - |b|^2 \ne 0$.
